# Get Scroll Pagination value in controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to get value of my **page_num** from jQuery to my controller but I cannot get the updated value I am just getting only a value that has been passed first time only. My scroll continuously display result when I scroll down and it does not stop and also it is not showing all the results it just showing first 6 and then repeat it continuously.

I am using jQuery ScrollPagination, but can't solve the problem - please help me.

This is my view:

```
<div id="main" style="width:760px">
    <div id='friend_display'>
    <?php if($list->num_rows() > 0  ){
     foreach($list->result() as $show){     ?>
            <!-- image box -->
            <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder' >

              <div class="photo-cover">
                <img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>
                    <!-- end photo name -->

            </div>
    <?php } } else { echo '<div align="center" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold">You have no Friends yet</div>';}?>
            <!-- end image-box -->
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end main -->
    </div>

 <div class="loading1" id="loading1">Wait a moment... it's loading!</div>
 <div class="loading1" id="nomoreresults">Sorry, no more results....!</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Friends extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('friends_model');
    }

    function find_friends($offset=0)
    {
            $friend['list']         =       $this->friends_model->find($offset);
            $this->load->view('friends_find_view',$friend);
    }


    function display_friends()
    {
            $offset =       $this->input->post('page_num');     
            $find   =       $this->friends_model->find($offset);

            if($find->num_rows() > 0        )
            {
                    foreach($find->result() as $show)
                    {       ?>

            <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder' >
                    <div class="photo-cover">
                            <img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>
                    <!-- end photo name -->

            </div>
    <?php } } else { exit; }?>
            <!-- end image-box -->
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php          
    }
  }
```

if i **echo $offset** then it show 6 every time bt in Script the **page_num** value is changing corectly.this is the main problem.

this is **model** code

```
         function find($offset)
         {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('users');

            $this->db->limit(6,$offset);
            $result = $this->db->get();
            return $result;        
          }
```

and finaly this is my **Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var page_num = 1;
    $(function(){
    $('#friend_display').scrollPagination({
            'contentPage': '<?=base_url()?>friends/display_friends', // the url you are fetching the results
            'contentData': {page_num:$('.image-box').size()}, // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
            'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
            'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
            'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
                    $('#loading1').fadeIn();       
            },
            'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
                     $('#loading1').fadeOut();
                     $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
                     page_num:$('.image-box').size();
            }
    });

    // code for fade in element by element
    $.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
            var delay = 0;
            return this.each(function(){
                    $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
                    delay += 100;
            });
    };
});    

</script>
```

I am asking this question 2nd time and hope this time i will get my solution, thanks.
you can also see full code here [Code for scroll pagination](http://pastebin.com/MC1KZm8y)

Comment: Instead of doing an echo $offest try doing a var_dump($this->input->post() )  and a var_dump($this->input->get() ). And post the results please

Comment: it return **string '6' (length=1)**

Comment: Are you sure $('.image-box').size() is passing the right values? have you debugged this piece of javascript?

Comment: yes i **alet( $('.image-box').size() )** it give correct value when scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first I'm going to give you an advice on your controller you shouldn't mix html with php

so this piece of code

```
function display_friends()
    {
            $offset =       $this->input->post('page_num');     
            $find   =       $this->friends_model->find($offset);

            if($find->num_rows() > 0        )
            {
                    foreach($find->result() as $show)
                    {       ?>

            <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder' >
                    <div class="photo-cover">
                            <img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>
                    <!-- end photo name -->

            </div>
    <?php } } else { exit; }?>
            <!-- end image-box -->
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php          
    }
```

We're going to split it out in two, creating a specific view for this method:

```
function display_friends(){
    $offset = $this->input->get('page_num');//notice that we changed this to get     
    $find   = $this->friends_model->find($offset);

    if($find->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data['rows'] = $find->result();
        $this->load->view('new_view', $data);
    } 
    echo '<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>'
}
```

And the new_view file will be something like this

```
   <?php foreach($rows as $show):?>

    <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder' >
    <div class="photo-cover">
        <img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>
    <!-- end photo name -->
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**EDIT**
The data passed to the plugin it's just passed one time, when it's instantiated, so `{page_num:$('.image-box').size()}` Is six when is instantiated, so the offset is always six

```
'contentPage': '<?=base_url()?>friends/display_friends', // the url you are fetching the results
        'contentData': {page_num:$('.image-box').size()}, // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
        'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
        'heightOffset': 10,
```

One solution is to edit scrollpagination and a crate a setter for the post data or an internal counter.

Comment: Just one more thing if the version of jquery that you're using is  >=1.8 just change $('.image-box').size() to $('.image-box'). length(). More info about that here http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: thanks for your help but still same problem i am getting jst 6 in controller

Comment: even with the get method? well in that case the problem is with this $('.image-box').size()

Comment: bt in my Javascript i alrt to chek bt is display correct value

Comment: and in the google chrome console, have you checked the xhr requests?

Comment: i m using mozila (firebug)

Comment: Or that, check the xhr requests and see wich data is being passed

Comment: where xhr is located in firebug

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26153/discussion-between-fabio-antunes-and-aysha-ali)